# How can I extract the address information from a Compressed ESRI shapefile datasource?

Tags: database, csv, gis, dbf, esri

When I download the zip file from the website it contains files with the following extensions:

.dbf
.prj
.sbn
.sbx
.shp
.shp.xml
.shx

Is this is a common data file format that I download or purchase a converter?
I think this is some kind of mapping data file but I all need are the addresses it contains to push into our existing database.

Specifically and related to programming. How can I setup a .NET Datasource to this group of files or just the .dbf file that actually contains the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much thanks to everyone who provided information. I found a CodePlex C# project that was exactly what I needed. I did have to make one small modification which I posted back on the project discussion board which was for an unknown column type of "F". But the command line program DBF2CSV worked beautifully to create a well formated csv from the dbf file. After a few minutes with Excel I had it ready to import to our MySQL database.

***The following project has a command line program that will convert a DBF file to CSV***
http://www.codeplex.com/fastdbf

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the address information you are looking for is stored in the dbf file. You can download the ESRI dBase driver from [here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13794).

There is sample code that shows this driver in use at http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=9&f=85&t=141422.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)

There are links at the bottom of the page that may help you. My only experience with these type of files was using other proprietary (and expensive) software.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could have you and Erikk share the answer because I appreciate both, but his was a bit more specific with links to a drive and code example in VB.

Answer (score 0):

The format for the dbf files is like the old DBase III format. The shp files contains the shapes and the shx are some kind of indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can open shapefile .dbf files in MS Access using DBase IV driver or directly in MS Excel (open as *.dbf)

:o)