# C# - trying to import a DBF into a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, dbf

Having a few issues importing a DBF into a datatable in Visual Studio. I have the below C# code:

```
        string FileDBF = "MyFileName.dbf";
        string FilePath = "C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\";
        //okay then, first we need to get the DBF - which can be queried like an SQL table
        OdbcConnection CC = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + FilePath + ";Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;");
        CC.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select id From " + FilePath + FileDBF, CC);
        OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
        }
        CC.Close();
        gvDBF.DataSource = dr;
        gvDBF.DataBind();
```

However, every time I run this it says there is an error in the FROM clause (at the OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); line).

I know it's targeting the file as I've tried it with an invalid file name, and it pops up then saying that the file can't be found.

Comment: The `Select` should be using a table name, not the path to the dbf.

Comment: Still not working with just the name.

Comment: What table is the `id` field in?

Comment: Just in a standard DBF file which, as far as I know, contains no tables - just the information.

Comment: It is an ESRI dbf file, if that helps.

Comment: Try hardcoding the path

Comment: Afraid I've already tried that too.

Comment: Try `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` before the `ExecuteReader` line.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's still not working either. Same error on the same line.

Comment: @user25730 I think you directly cannot execute a `Select` query on a ESRI dbf file. You will need DBase drivers to have it read in or exported to MS Access or the MS Excel. Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150301/how-can-i-extract-the-address-information-from-a-compressed-esri-shapefile-datas) could do some help to you in reading data from `dbf` file.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think so. Fortunately an Access equivalent is available.